# inverse system vs inverse sequence

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I am wondering about such problem. Let $\{X_i,\phi_{ij},I\}$ be an inverse system, where the directed set $I$ has such property that there exists a sequence $i_1 \leq i_2\leq\cdots\subset I$ such that for every $j\in I$ there exists $i_n$ with $i_n\geq j$.

So it gives us inverse sequence indexed by the elements of the sequence. Are there any connections between inverse limits of these inverse systems? Maybe they are the same sometimes? I am especially interested in inverse limits of topological spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the inverse limit of the full system as $A$ and of the subsystem as $B$. We have a map from $A$ to $B$ given on $X_{i_j}$ by the composition of the identity on $X_{i_j}$ with the projection of $A$ onto $X_{i_j}$ and a map $B\to A$ given similarly on the $X_{i_j}$ and on the other $X_i$ by composing the identity on $X_i$ with the given map $X_{i_n}\to X_i$ and the projection $A\to X_{i_n}$. You can check directly that both compositions are the identity, since their components are the projections $A\to X_i$ and $B\to X_{i_j}$.

Answer (score -1):

The sequence is also `directed`, and `cofinal in I`. It's a theorem that the inverse limits of the inverse systems are isomorphic.

Comment: Do you know where could I find the proof of this theorem? I only found that it is true when spaces are compact.

Comment: In the first place, it's a general theorem about inverse limits of sets. For topological spaces and uniform spaces, you can find it in N. Bourbaki, General Topology, Ch. I, § 4.4 and Ch. II, § 2.7 respectively. It is also true for many other structures.

Comment: So for example if the poset I would be finite then, the inverse limit would be just the space that corresponds to the greatest element?

Comment: You're absolutely right.

Comment: It's true in any category, as I showed.

Comment: If the category has inverse limits…

Comment: It seems that we do not need to assume that we have an inverse limit but I think that analogous theorem would be true for general limits of diagrams. Of course we would have to define cofinality in this case. (We assume that $D$ has limits).

Am I right or going in right way? 

For example if we have a diagram $F: J\to D$ a cofinal subdiagram would be $K:I\to D$ where  K is a subcategory of J that for every object $F(A)$ for $A\in J$ there exist an object $B\in K$ such that there exist a morphism $F(B)\to F(A)$ or something in this way.

Comment: @pw1822: I must say I don't know much about  diagrams in categories. I've just seen that inverse systems in a category $C$ are just functors from a small cofiltered category $I$ to $C$.